# Semantic UI dropdown does not trigger in Meteor app

Tags: jquery, meteor, iron-router

I have this function when the header is rendered:

```
Template.header.onRendered(function (){
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Which is working fine when I test my app locally. But on production, the dropdown never triggers. I suspect that a waitOn function in Iron Router is causing a delay, so that .dropdown() is run before the page is in fact complete.

My route:

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'Home',
    template: 'Home',
    waitOn: function() {
    if (Meteor.userId())
      return Meteor.subscribe('posts');
  }
});
```

Suggestion on how to make sure that dropdown() is run after everything is ready?

Comment: My question is why you want to trigger a dropdown on rendering the template. Maybe you should use a different widget that will display without needing to be triggered like this?

Comment: Semantic UI docs states that dropdown menus, and other similar components, has to be initialized like this.